# Changing styling on current page link not working on index page

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using this to change styling for current page's link in nav bar. It works like charm on all the other pages except the index page in which it changes styling for every link in nav bar. Why is that?

```
$("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").addClass("current-page-link");
```

Comment: What does index page href look like? What is pathname also?

Comment: probably because the location doesn't actually include index but just the domain name, which every link starts with, if the index is the first link that is found, you could always make sure only one link ever has the styling applied by using `$("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").eq(0).addClass("current-page-link");`

Comment: There's no link to index page in nav bar. Index is https://sitename.com and all the other pages https://sitename.com/page-title

Comment: my point exactly

Comment: $("a[href*='" + location.pathname + "']").eq(0).addClass("current-page-link"); got it working. Thank you

Comment: Does using `$=` instead of `*=` in the attribute selector work for you?

Comment: Even better. Thanks man